# Dropzone JS Change Filename Before Upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I'm using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to handle uploading of files. I would really like to be able to modify the original name of the file before uploading it to S3. It would be nice to just be able to use [dropzone's processing file hook](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-processing) like shown below, but it appears none of the changes I make to this file object persist...

```
myDropone.on('processingfile', function(file) {
  console.log(file.name) // 'Randy.png'
  file.name = 'my-custom-name.png';
  console.log(file.name) // 'Randy.png'
});
```

Even when trying to modify this File object in the console changes do not persist. I'm losing my mind...

[image]

Does anyone see what I'm missing here? Or is there a better way to modify the name of a file before uploading it with Dropzone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

File is a HTML 5 file object, and some of it's properties is read-only as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

But, you can set a new property for your file object like:

```
myDropone.on("sending", function(file) {
    file.myCustomName = "my-new-name" + file.name;
    console.log(file.myCustomName);
});
```

Edit: Also, the documentation says, the recommended way to send aditional params in the body of the post action is:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
     // Will send the filesize along with the file as POST data.
     formData.append("filesize", file.size);
     formData.append("fileName", "myName");
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `renameFile` option in dropzone.js that will let you change the uploaded file name.

```
// Dropzone declaration
...
renameFile: function (file) {
    return 'my_new_file_name.png';
}
```

For older versions of Dropzone the option name is `renameFilename`.