# How to get to sent info in Java sevrverside?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, dropzone.js

How do I get to the info sent with this code mentioned in [Dropzone JS Change Filename Before Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757331/dropzone-js-change-filename-before-upload)

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
     // Will send the filesize along with the file as POST data.
     formData.append("filesize", file.size);
     formData.append("fileName", "myName");
});
```

Honestly I dont really know where to put the above code either. I feel they kinda dropped the ball on the tutorial, because code is kinda of just "floating" without context, also I cant find a list or anything as to what I can look for to query and get info from on serverside.

Usually with easy home made newb ajax calls I just use request.getParameter("someInfo"). But now Im totally lost.

Comment: Is it really related to java?

Comment: Well, I would prefer how to get the info in java. But since I imagine there is some order to what is sent, there should be some order quite language agnostic. Like with normal forms, I get the feeling most languages use the attribute names of the elements to get to their value. If some info is called "Orange" one probably uses that to get to the info, albeit in different manner according to language, but you still need "Orange". My problem Is i dont know if there are pears? Are there Apples?

Comment: Also, despite of the example, where I imagine I use "fileName" to get to the value "myName" on serverside, I just cant get to it. I dont know how.