# Is it possible to get the foldername for a file uploaded with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js as a part of my flask application, where the user can upload multiple folders at the same time. But sometimes the most valuable information about the files is the folder name.

An example could be:

Folder A

- sample.txt
- img.png

Folder B

- sample.txt
- img.png

Would it here be possible to to register which files comes from Folder A and which comes from Folder B, assuming that they drag-n-drop the whole folder into the dropzone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with assistance from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757814/2052575) and MDN's article on [Using FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

If you define your dropzone like this in the template:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#my-awesome-dropzone",
    { url: "/upload",
});
```

You must then add an event handler for the `sending` event, which takes the `file.fullPath` string, and adds it to a blob which becomes part of the `multipart/form-data` submission.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  // get the original fullPath and add it to the multipart form.
  var blob = new Blob([file.fullPath], { type: "text/plain"});
  formData.append("originalPath", blob);
});
```

Note that this essentially adds a second file called `blob` with the `text/plain` mimetype to your form submission.  To visualize this, within the upload route on your Flask server, you can `print(request.files)` which gives:

```
ImmutableMultiDict(
    [('originalPath', <FileStorage: 'blob' ('text/plain')>),
     ('file', <FileStorage: 'up.txt' ('text/plain')>)
    ])
```

So to extract the actual string from that on the server end you could do:

```
original_path = request.files['originalPath'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Note that from the frontend perspective, dropzone doesn't know about parent folders relative to the file or folder that was dropped, so:

- dropping a file called `up.txt` into Dropzone, `original_path` will be `'undefined'`.
- dropping a folder called `untitled folder` containing a file called `up.txt` into Dropzone, `original_path` will be `'untitled folder/up.txt'`.

You should build some functionality on the backend to validate the info coming in, and parse these strings accordingly.